# Deadlock in transactions

Tags: database, transactions

I think the following transaction schedule has a deadlock (t3 waits for t1 to unlock y), but I am not able to form a waiting cycle between transactions t1, t2 and t3. The question is, is there a deadlock or not?

| T1 | T2 | T3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | read_lock(X); |
|  |  | read_item(X); |
|  | read_lock(X); |  |
| read_lock(Y); |  |  |
| read_item(Y); |  |  |
|  | read_item(X); |  |
|  | unlock(X); |  |
| write_lock(X); |  |  |
|  |  | write_lock(Y); |
|  |  | read_item(Y); |
|  | write_lock(Y); |  |
|  | read_item(Y); |  |
| unlock(Y); |  |  |
|  | write_item(Y); |  |
|  | unlock(Y); |  |
| unlock(X); |  | write_item(Y); |
|  |  | unlock(X); |
|  |  | unlock(Y); |

<sup>*(Notes on the formatted table. The image doesn't make it clear whether T3 executes `read_item(Y)` before T2 executes `write_lock(Y)`; the table assumes that it does.
The image appears to have T1 executing `unlock(X)` at the same time as T3 executes `write_item(Y)`; the table lets that stand.)*</sup>

[image: Image of transaction schedule]

Comment: Please don't include images of text — make the text copyable in the question.  Making it into a Markdown table requires some extra knowledge (that tables exist, and how to create them).  All else apart, that makes the material more easily readable.

Comment: Sorry, i'll do better next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS, the first three operations in T2 have no effect on the overall transaction schedule because they all occur before T1 executes `write_lock(X)`.

There is a deadlock between T1 and T3 because:

- T3 locks X
- T1 locks Y
- T3 attempts to lock Y and is blocked by T1's lock.
- T1 attempts to lock X and is blocked by T3's lock.

Neither transaction will release its locks.  The transaction schedule from T3's `read_item(Y)` onwards is hypothetical because of the deadlock.

It is largely immaterial that T2 is also blocked by T1's lock on Y; the deadlock has already occurred before T2 attempts that operation.